# Connect to checkpoint VPN

Tags: networking, 13.10, vpn

My company uses a couple of Checkpoint VPN's. With my Windows laptop I use *Endpoint Security* to connect.

For our corporate VPN I can use the *SNX* client in Ubuntu to connect.

However we also have a more secure division and are bound by compliance restrictions not to use the SSL network extender on that one. So since I have gone through the trouble of locking down my Ubuntu machine I want to be able to connect but can not find a VPN client that will connect to Checkpoint.

I found an article for *Raccon* but it may be a bit beyond my Linux skills to setup. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use Raccoon for IPSEC setup.  (It's not updated anymore nor is it really 'safe' to use, as strongswan is preferred).  I'd follow the answer given here, to check with the IT department for the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your IT department if they have the IPSec VPN license on the Security Gateway. If so, you can connect without the Check Point VPN client, and instead use the L2TP VPN built into Windows, Ubuntu, and mobile phones.

[More Information on Check Point's website](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk67820#Additional%20Remote%20Access%20Solutions)